# AWS - Lambda fuction that use getSomething method. How to create correct request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Hi Guys I have imo easy question.

I've made service class with CRUD methods, I have to create Lambda class for getObject method that find object in database by id, for example:

```
public Product getProduct(String id){
    return dbService.get(Product.class, id);
}
```

I wanted to send id in request body but it doesn't work:

```
public class GetProductLambda extends Lambda {

@Override
public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
    super.handleRequest(input, context);
    try {
        String id = RequestUtil.parseRequestBody(input, String.class);
        KitchenService kitchenService = appComponent.getKitchenService();
        Product product = kitchenService.getProduct(id);
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_OK, product);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

    }


}
}
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change?

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @Stu yes, in line with String id... I have this error message: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.lang.Class<T>